# Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce - buy one click

Tags: google-analytics

I want to send purchase event to Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce from "**buy one click**" form.
Do i need to do it the same as for order?
like this? or i need use something else for this purpose?

```
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
  id: 'T12345',
  affiliation: 'Google Store - Online',
  revenue: '28.03',
  tax: '2.14',
  shipping: '4.00',
  coupon: 'SUMMER2013'
});

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Not sure what a "buy one click" is. Do you mean something like "one-click purchase", where the user, presumably logged in, just needs to click on one button and the purchase is instant?

Comment: Yes."**one-click purchase**"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to track the order purcahses you have to do it, but take care, usually the purchase is tracked on the "Thanks you" or "Confirmation" Page, if you implement this on the button you can duplicate the purchase

Comment: Can I use this code even "one-click purchase" works via ajax? (Can I run it after page load)

Comment: Yes, If the ga() object is defined you just can execute the same on the success but change the ga('send', 'pageview'); to use an event instead (it's more political). here is an example on Jquery function testAjax() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "getvalue.php",  
      success: function() {
       ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
  id: 'T12345',
  affiliation: 'Google Store - Online',
  revenue: '28.03',
  tax: '2.14',
  shipping: '4.00',
  coupon: 'SUMMER2013'
});       ga('send', 'event', 'ecommerce', 'purchase', 'confirmation');

      }
   });
   return data; 
}

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try